# ¿ Que significa este mensaje de Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, ubuntu

Comenzó a salirme el siguiente mensaje en la parte derecha de abajo de la pantalla de Visual Studio :

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/snap/code'    Origen:
>   Servicio de actualización.

De repente he perdido todas las extensiones que tenia instaladas, y las que me quedaron, esta in operativas, cuando las des-habilito y vuelvo a habilitar, me muestra de nuevo el mensaje que mostré anteriormente.
Trabajo con Ubuntu y la verdad es que no recuerdo como instale Visual Studio.

¿Alguna idea de por qué me tengo esos errores?

Comment: Instalaste VS vía snap según parece

Comment: Hi @Arg0s , how can I correct that?

Comment: Sinceramente no lo sé. No utilizo VS Code. ENOENT es el sterror que se origina cuando se llama a un archivo o directorio que no existe. Viendo que puedes comunicarte en inglés, si nadie sabe responder a tu pregunta, te recomiendo que, después de recopilar todos los datos, abras un issue en https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode . Lo que me lleva a la 2ª sugerencia: Estás en SO en español (hecho ex profeso para quien no habla inglés)  y suelen borrar o cerrar las preguntas y comentarios hechos en ingles, así que te sugiero que no utilices el inglés en este lugar. Saludos